# Do something ontouch in libgdx

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I have written the following code. It is simple rectangle in middle of the screen. I want the rectangle to move -50 in y direction onClick (direction is just for illustration purposes only). Despite trying various methods. I cannot get the code to work. I am not sure if I am doing something fundamentally wrong. I would appreciate some direction from better learned minds.

```
package com.mygdx.gameobjects;

import com.badlogic.gdx.InputProcessor;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Rectangle;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector2;

public class Hero extends Rectangle implements InputProcessor{

private Rectangle hero;
private Vector2 position;

public Hero(){
    position = new Vector2(x, y);
    hero = new Rectangle(position.x+68-10, position.y+204-30-20, 20, 20);
}

public void update (float delta) {

}

public void onClick() {
    position.y = -50;
}

public Rectangle getHero() {
    return hero;
}

@Override
public boolean touchDown(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
    onClick();
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean touchUp(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean keyDown(int keycode) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean keyUp(int keycode) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean keyTyped(char character) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean touchDragged(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean mouseMoved(int screenX, int screenY) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean scrolled(int amount) {
    return false;
}
}
```

Comment: Have you already drawn your rectangle on screen?

Comment: Did you set Hero class as inputProcessor? Type the following line in the constructor of Hero class.

    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(this);

Comment: I've addes Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(this); as suggested. However, not much is happening on screen.